# Searching good JavaScript formatter for eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, code-formatting, formatter

I am using eclipse as my IDE but I don't like the installed formatters. I also builded my own one but didn't get it to work like I want it to. For example things like that happen often:
[image]

Is there somebody out there with a good JavaScript formatter or a link with a list of some. I only found a few (e.g. the google formatter) but I don't like one of them.

Comment: I used Aptana Studio (based on eclipse), which has a much better JavaScript-Formatter until I changed to WebStorm for developing Web-Stuff.

Comment: I don't want to use this plugin in eclipse because I already installed all this plugins which Aptana comes up with.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the formatting preferences individually.

Window->Preferences->JavaScript->Code Style->Formatter

You'll have to save them as a new file. The only issue i have is that the object declaration won't use tabs instead of spaces for the property declarations.